# A Quantum Mechanics question that no one can answer

Tags: quantum-mechanics

One of the professors in our department asked the following question on a Quantum Mechanics exam:

> Write me a Quantum Mechanics question below. If I can answer it, you
>   will get 6 points and if I cannot you will get 12!

Now, I wonder whether there is such a question or not. What I mean is: **Are there any open questions in the formalism of Quantum Mechanics? Is QM a complete theory as it is?**

Comment: One of the weirdest exam question I've seen...

Comment: A question that uses some kind of "incompleteness" of QM does not qualify, as it would not be a QM question. And the 12P are simply achieved, just write some crazy potential and ask for analytical expressions for the bound state eigenenergies.

Comment: your prof should want something about your choice and his answer capacity. You know only that you must find something around a 6/12 superposition. Try to build some paradoxal choice in a meta question :)

Comment: @SebastianRiese Why would a question that involves the "incompleteness" of quantum mechanics stop being a question of quantum mechanics? Such questions seem to me to be the most *important* questions for quantum mechanics. Questions can be "in" multiple disciplines...

Comment: Maybe you should get 24 points if you can ask a classical mechanics question that he cannot answer.

Comment: "What is the answer to a Quantum Mechanics question which you are unable to answer?" This is a "Quantum Mechanics question" that cannot be answered. If your professor is a good sport, you should get your extra 6! ;)

Comment: This question (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: I know, I know, I'm being boring but this question is both a list question and too broad. Therefore I vote to close it.

Comment: @innisfree "One of"? Do share! ;)

Comment: Question:   Is Schrodinger's cat dead or alive?   :-)
Answer:   Yes.

Comment: @JohnRennie you should have known that your students will come here to ask.

Comment: One of the best professors in our faculty asks students to think out a paper for Nature journal on topic during the exam. As weird as they may sound, both questions are great. They push you beyond the passive reception of knowledge to creative usage of it - that's the way to make knowledge truly yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I initially said that quantum mechanics is generally **not** considered a complete theory, but several people in the comments disagree, so I guess I'll have to make a more explicit case for this. In any case, it seems this matter is not as "settled" as I thought it was. If you just want my examples of questions, just skip to the bulleted points.

Specifically, the following unanswered question is a central one of modern day theoretical physics:

- What is the best way to unify quantum mechanics and gravity?

Notice that I said *gravity*, not special relativity. Quantum field theories are effective in unifying quantum mechanics with special relativity, but they don't touch gravity. Indeed, when you apply quantum mechanics to regimes where *both* quantum effects and relativistic effects are expected to be important, e.g. the area around black holes, quantum mechanics gives us answers that are **wrong**. Perhaps we have different definitions of complete, but I'm not sure how you can say that a theory that makes *wrong* predictions is complete.

Some people were also arguing that this example lies outside the domain of quantum mechanics. I'd argue against this notion. Quantum mechanics, while only noticeable at very small scales, is expected to (and largely does) reduce to the classical results at larger scales. Quantum mechanics does *not* e.g. predict that *people* will randomly pass through walls (with any reasonable change), it only predicts that *particles* will. Similarly, Special relativity and General relativity correctly reduce to our observations of slow-moving objects and less-extreme gravity. So, I think it is imprecise to argue that certain regimes lie outside quantum mechanics in any sense that allows quantum mechanics to be straight-up *wrong* in those domains. I think that a complete theory would not be so clearly inconsistent with reality. Again, perhaps we are thinking of different notions of complete.

Another example of a question that has not been answered:

- What is the correct interpretation (e.g. Copenhagen, Many-Worlds, etc...) of quantum mechanics? This question might never be answered, and indeed might not be a meaningful question, but it is also possible that it *is* a meaningful question, and *might* be answered in the future by new data that takes these ideas farther from meta-physics. In any case, while we certainly don't have an answer to this question, I did not mean to imply that the status of this question implies the incompleteness of quantum mechanics.

These are very "high level" questions, and perhaps you were looking for something more concrete. Some examples of more concrete questions:

- Find an analytic 3-body (i.e. wavefunctions of the two electrons and the nucleus) solution to the helium atom including the coulomb potential and and electron-electron repulsion.
- Develop an accurate theory of high-temperature superconductivity.

I might be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure none of the questions above have accepted answers. A couple examples of computationally difficult problems that *do* have solutions:

- Solve the *hydrogen atom* potential for an electron in parabolic-cylindrical coordinates.
- Find the entropy of a system of neutral atoms trapped in an optical lattice.

Hope this helps

Comment: I strongly disagree with your first statement - I think quantum mechanics is absolutely a complete theory. Rather then getting all upset about Bell's theorem, I'll just point out that neither the interpretation of quantum mechanics nor it's incompatibility with GR (partially solved anyway with QFT) is "part of QM". The first is meta-QM, and the second is explicitly outside of the theory, since it's not supposed to apply at large scales anyway. These are problems in physics at large, not QM.

Comment: Just to be clear, I think your second two questions are right on the money :-)

Comment: I 99% like this answer - I'm also just not sure about the "not complete" statement.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a more explicit argument for why I think quantum mechanics is incomplete.

Comment: The biggest problem with your post is that you are mistaking quantum mechanics and quantum field theory applications of quantum mechanics for each other. QM, the theory, does not contain quantum gravity and does not have to. At this point it's not even clear that gravity is a force. There are probably more arguments against than for that notion.

Comment: @CuriousOne by your apparent conception then, every theory is a complete theory, which makes the notion of completeness rather useless.

If any theory is to be considered incomplete, it is one that will change in a fundamental way to encompass more material and phenomena. I think it is fair to say that we know that quantum mechanics will change since we know that right now it makes bad predictions. I am not mistaking the theory with the applications, I am using the applications to understand the development of the theory.

Comment: The notion of completeness is useless if you include applications of the theory. In that sense classical mechanics is incomplete and will never be complete because there is an infinite number of special potentials and cases for which those potentials have interesting solutions. By completeness I simply mean that the finite assumptions of the theory are set and won't change anymore. I think we can agree that this is the case for quantum mechanics since we can calculate physically relevant quantities with it just fine? What other assumptions would you like to include?

Comment: The real incompleteness in QM is the one Schrödinger pointed at with the cat-in-a-box gedankenexperiment. The selection of a wavevector on measurement is wrapped up in relative states and decoherence in a way that is only partially described on quantitative level.

Comment: @CuriousOne I think I see our problem now. The black hole example isn't just a specific problem that we don't have a solution to yet, in the same way a new unique potential in either quantum or classical mechanics is. The problem is that we **can** apply quantum to the problem, and when we do, the answer quantum gives us is **wrong**. I'm not saying that we need to solve every possible application of the theory, I'm saying that because we can see that quantum gets something so wrong, it is likely that it fundamentally *will* change.

Comment: Quantum mechanics doesn't give you any answers to problems that haven't been tested experimentally or observationally to some extent, yet. Everything about quantum gravity is completely fictional, at this point. It's not even hypothetical because we don't have the necessary technology to test any of the possible hypotheses, yet. As much as I dread having to pull the definition of science card (it shouldn't be necessary), this is the point where I will. In any case, unless you have new observations that contradict standard quantum mechanics, then you have nothing to modify or extend it with.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm definitely not saying that I have the answer to how to modify or extend it, I'm only saying that I think it is reasonable to assume that at some point it will probably be modified or replaced. You don't have to go to a black hole and measure things to see that quantum mechanics clearly breaks down at such regimes, the predictions it **does** make are nonsensical, infinities everywhere.

Comment: I think we have agreement on that. I don't believe that quantum mechanics as we know it is the final theory, either. It is probably more of a very general border case, like thermodynamics. The problem, right now, is that we don't have experimental access to the regime where quantum mechanics fails (if it fails). I am not sure where you think QM makes nonsensical predictions? The problems of quantum field theory are not linked to QM proper, if I understand it correctly, but to the dimensionality of interactions.

Comment: The idea is that a singularity is small, so you need quantum mechanics to describe it, but it is also extremely massive, involving significant gravity, so quantum mechanics can't describe it. The line about infinities everywhere is honestly something that I've just repeatedly heard when people talk about attempts to mix QM and GR.

I haven't take QFT or GR courses yet, so perhaps I shouldn't be so confident, but I've always just pictured QFT it as something of an extension of QM. In any case I've been lumping the formalism of QM and QFT together throughout this conversation.

Answer (score 7):

Interesting question, but there are **many** possible answers. In the area of molecular physics one might ask...

"Calculate the probability of an electron with 100eV ionizing a C$_{60}$ molecule"

this is a QM question that (s)he would not have been able to answer, but it is not really about the formalism of QM. The question could probably be described in QM, but it would be way too complicated to solve without a powerful computer and various approximations.

Comment: Here is a simple sounding question about a formalism of QM: at which point a collection of interacting quantum particles becomes a "classical apparatus" for the purposes of the collapse axiom? How does one produce from such a system the self-adjoint operator into whose eigenstates a test particle will collapse after interacting with it?

Answer (score 4):

Open up the chapter on perturbation theory in any quantum mechanics textbook and pick any Hamiltonian you see. Chances are an exact solution to that quantum system isn't known. Ask your Professor to find the exact solution. For example one question could be:

Find the exact energy spectrum and eigenfunctions of the following Hamiltonian:

$$H = \frac{1}{2}p^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{\lambda}{4!}x^4.$$

Answer (score 3):

> Calculate the fine structure constant from first principles (i.e. without recourse to the empirical values of $\epsilon_0$, $e$, $\hbar$, and $c$)
> *Comment:* The fine structure constant is undoubtedly the most fundamental pure (dimensionless) number in all of physics. It relates the basic constants of electromagnetism (the change of the electron), relativity (the speed of light), and quantum mechanics (Plank's constant). If you can solve [this], you will have the most certain Nobel Prize in history waiting for you. But I wouldn't recommend spending a lot of time on it right now; many smart people have tried, and all (so far) have failed.

Problem 6.11 b "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" David J. Griffiths

Answer (score 0):

Ask him why you treat the molecules in a gas as particles if according to QM their wave function will quickly spread out and will become   planar unlocalized waves (it has been asked in this forum a few times in different formats but never well answered)